# Position text centered in the right 66% of the screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My layout displays a logo at the upper left corner of the screen, and I'd like to display a header text at its right side.
I found that in a responsive layout, whatever the screen width, it would look nice if I'd be able to center the header text in the right 66% of the screen.
Is there any smart way to achieve that with CSS?

Basically, my current layout code is like

```
<div id="header">
 <div id="title">
 </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.header {width:100%; height:92px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; background:#7196CB url(/css/header_logo.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, quite simply:

```css
.title {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    width: 66%;
}
```

You may want to introduce a clearfix element into your `.header` element after using `float`.

#### Demo

```css
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.title {
  background: #eee;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    Hello, world!
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

Comment: @TeeJay the question's title is "Position text centered in the right 66% of the screen?". I have changed 33% to 66% now though!

Comment: yeah, I noticed that, but no big deal. Thanks a lot - it works now!